# PostGIS ST_Contains vs point chunking in terms of scalability

Tags: postgresql, postgis, scalability

I have a very large database of Points that I am storing in a Postgres database. Every second, a client is retrieving all the points that are close to the physical location of the client, say 1 km. My target is to make sure to have to most scalable way of storing and retrieving those points, even at ridiculously big numbers of Points. Apart from reading, a client can add a Point at any time. In my view, there are two ways of dealing with Points in a scalable manner, which is either using PostGIS with ST_Contains (I am assuming it does some optimizations) or storing the points in chunks, but I am not sure which one is better. What would be the best approach?

Comment: `st_contains` is for polygon... have a look at `st_dwithin` with a spatial index

Comment: So it seems like a spatial index is a better version of point chunking. Thank you!